# What is the best way to extract this int from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, int, parseint

Here are examples of some input that I may be given

```
1,4
34,2
-99,20
```

etc.

Therefore negative values are included and 1, 2, 3, etc digits are possible. Commas are not the only delimiters, just an example. But Non integer values are the reason parseInt won't work. What can I code that will allow me to parse the above 3 inputs so that I get this?

```
1
34
-99
```

Comment: What other delimiters are there?

Comment: Are you sure commas are the delimiters? Because a number like *4 34* makes no sense to me... Either does *2 -99*. Looks like the spaces are the delimiters, and the commas are used as periods (standard in Europe for example). So the numbers would be `1.4 34.2 -99.20`

Comment: Line breaks implied separate inputs, I should have said.

Comment: d := @set(@tuple(1,2),@tuple(3,4));

This is an example of a full line. So the only other delimiter is a bracket I guess? All the answers so far are great but I can't decide which one I should choose!

Comment: I think something that creates a substring up until a non int character is what I'm looking for actually.

Comment: If there is no delimiter, is the line still valid? e.g. if you are given a line with only "1" instead "1,4", do you want to output 1?

Comment: Better to use `"\\D+(?<![+-])"` as delimiter which means 1 or more non-digit text excluding `+` and `-` signs. Pls check my answer for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
String str = "1,4 34,2 -99,20";
String[] arr = str.split("\\D+(?<![+-])");
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2)
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1
34
-99
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions (regex).

A simple example of breaking with commas:

```
String[] values = string.split(",")
for (String a : values) {
    Integer.parseInt(a);
}
```

Comment: check for string with length 0  to avoid NumberFormatException

Comment: Also, OP only wants the first value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very open question... I will suggest that you first go through your string, and format all the numbers correctly substituting all the commas for dots... Then you need to split it, and then you need to parse each value.

For each step you can find a lot of help googling.

ie.

- Step 1. String substitution java
- Step 2. String split java
- Step 3. String to int java

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all characters except digits with an empty string and then do a parseInt

```
String intStr = inputStr.replaceAll("[^0-9]+","");
int i = Integer.parseInt(intStr);
```

Comment: And that won't combine 1 and 2 into one int, 12?

Comment: Yes, the regex should be more like `"[^\\d].*"`. But it's not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use commas, you could do

```
String numbers = "1,34,-99";
String[] splitNums = numbers.split(",");
int[] ints = null;
for(int i = 0; i < splitNums.length(); i++) 
{
    ints[i] = Integer.valueOf(splitNums[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want input to be valid only if there is a delimiter, use `"([\\-0-9]*)[,]+.*"` instead.

If you want to add additional delimiters, e.g. `:`, add to the delimiter set, e.g. `"([\\-0-9]*)[,|:]+.*"`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String s1 = "-99,20";
            System.out.println(getNumber(s1));

            s1 = "1,4";
            System.out.println(getNumber(s1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static int getNumber(String s1) throws Exception {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\-0-9]*)[,]*.*");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s1);
        if(m.find()) {
            return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        } 

        throw new Exception("Not valid input");
    }
}
```