# How can I find int values within a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, int, parseint

I have a string, e.g. `"ksl13<br>m4n"`, and I want to remove all non-digit characters in order to get the int 134.

`Integer.parseInt(s)` obviously isn't going to work, but not sure how else to go about it.

Comment: Use class `Pattern` or `String#replaceAll(String, String)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to extract this int from a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180849/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-this-int-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regex first:

```
String s = "ksl13 m4n";
String clean = s.replaceAll("\\D+",""); //remove non-digits
```

Then you can use `Integer.parseInt`:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(clean);
```

and `i` will be `134`.

Comment: @FraserPrice `\\D+` will remove anything that is not one of: `0123456789`.

Comment: Really! `\\D+` equivalent to `[a-z|A-Z]`, means replace all except Decimals?

Comment: @Azad `\\D+` is equivalent to `[^0-9]+`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a regex, you can do something like this:

```
private String buildNumber(String str) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)) 
            strBuilder.append(ch);
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Then you can turn it to an `int` using [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

See [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) for additional information.

Comment: Just a sidenote that `Character.isDigit` is a little more broad than `\d` from regex since it can match international digit characters ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))).

Comment: Indeed. If this is important he can easily check for `0-9` digits using `>'0' && <'9'` for example.

Answer (score 0):

String str = "ksl13 m4n";
String strArray[] = str.split("\D+"); will give you the array of integer values

Answer (score 0):

```
    input          output

    abcd1234        1234
    abcd            0
    123abcd456      123
```

only for returning the first sequence of digits available in the string

```
public static int intValueOfString( String strVal) {
    
    char[] charArry= strVal.toCharArray();
    List<Character> myDigitcharList = new ArrayList();
    int isDegitsAvailable = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < charArry.length ; i++ ) {
        if (Character.isDigit(strVal.charAt(i))) {
            myDigitcharList.add(charArry[i]);
            isDegitsAvailable++;
        } else {
            
            if (isDegitsAvailable > 0) {
                break;
            }
            
        }
    }    
    
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder("");
    
    if (myDigitcharList.size() > 0) {
        for (Character x : myDigitcharList) {
            sb.append(x);
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```